Camel in Spring Boot isn't reading application.yml settings
I have set the following in my application.yml:
camel:
  component:
    http:
      follow-redirects: true

.. but still redirects aren't followed:
An error occurred while processing the exchange: SOME.EXAMPLE {
CamelMulticastComplete=true, CamelCharsetName=UTF-8, CamelRecipientListEndpoint=https://some.url/xmlfeed.zip, 
CamelCorrelationId=0D84F148E234847-0000000000000007, CamelMulticastIndex=0, 
CamelToEndpoint=https://some.url/xmlfeed.zip, CamelExceptionCaught=org.apache.camel.http.base.HttpOperationFailedException: 
HTTP operation failed invoking https://some.url/xmlfeed.zip with statusCode: 301, 
redirectLocation: https://some.url/xmlfeed-redirected.zip} 0D84F148E234847-000000000000001A, {
CamelHttpMethod=GET, CamelRedelivered=true, CamelRedeliveryCounter=1, 
Content-Type=text/plain, supplier=foo, user-agent=foo-bar/2.0}

I'm using the Camel Spring Boot Starter, v3.22.2

The solution was to use the org.apache.camel.springboot:camel-http-starter dependency instead of org.apache.camel:camel-http, as described in the Camel HTTP component docs.
